# MalwareBytes re-installation removes single-file scan from context menu

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, context-menu, windows-defender, malwarebytes

I was forced to reinstall MalwareBytes in the process of updating the virus definition.  MalwareBytes is now the main AV.  The Windows Security Centre has a `Virus & threat protection` subpanel showing MalwareBytes as the active AV.  The subpanel also has a `Manage settings` showing that "You're using other antivirus providers".  I don't recall if that was how I set things up beforehand, but I'll roll with it.

After the aforementioned re-install, however, the context menu no longer provides the option to scan with Defender.  I used to routinely scan a file with all 3 of the following antimalware apps from the context menu: Defender, MalwareBytes, and SpybotS&D.

*How can I restore the context menu option to scan with Defender?*

**Contextual details**

Regardless of my configuration in the past, I may have had real time protection completely disabled in the past.  With the re-install, real-time protection is enabled (all 4 features: web, malware, ransomware, exploit).

The `Virus & threat protection` subpanel also has `Windows Defender Antivirus options`, where "You can keep your current provider, and have Windows Defender Antirvius periodically check for threats".  Enabling this does *not* restore Defender scanning in a file's context menu.

The following suggests that you can restore Defender scanning to the context menu by not registering MalwareBytes, but I don't want to do that.  I don't why it is necessary to remove on-demand scanning by Defender simply because it isn't the main AV:

https://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/95206-windows-10-context-menu-option-scan-windows-defender.html

In Windows 8, the following uses the registry to add Defender scanning to the context menu.  As it mucks with the registry of another OS, I'm reluctant to blindly forge ahead with it on Windows 10:

https://www.eightforums.com/threads/scan-with-windows-defender-add-in-windows-8.15790

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: plutomaniac
; http://www.eightforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15790-scan-windows-defender-add-windows-8-a.html

; Folder Scan

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\WindowsDefender]
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\\\Windows Defender\\\\EppManifest.dll"
"MUIVerb"="Scan with Windows Defender"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\WindowsDefender\Command]
@="cmd.exe /s /c \"\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe\" -SignatureUpdate & echo. & cmd.exe /s /c \"\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe\" -scan -scantype 3 -file \"%1 \"\"\" & echo. & pause"

; File Scan

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WindowsDefender]
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\\\Windows Defender\\\\EppManifest.dll"
"MUIVerb"="Scan with Windows Defender"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WindowsDefender\Command]
@="cmd.exe /s /c \"\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe\" -SignatureUpdate & echo. & cmd.exe /s /c \"\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe\" -scan -scantype 3 -file \"%1 \"\"\" & echo. & pause"
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the plunge and executed the registry modification alluded in the posted question.  The context menu now contains an option to scan a file with Defender.  Unfortunately, I just noticed that the context menu option to scan the file with MalwareBytes is missing.  It may have been missing before running the registry modification.  It looks like the MalwareBytes re-installation might have blown away both options....so now looking for how to restore the context menu option to scan a file with MalwayreBytes.

*Sigh*

It's like musical AVs.  C'mon, MalwareBytes.....anyways, the solution is hinted at here: https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038524694-Context-menu-not-working-in-Malwarebytes-for-Windows-v3.  When I followed the instructions, I found that appearance in the context menu was already enabled.  At least that's what MalwareBytes thought.  I succeeded in forcing it to be re-enabled by first disabling, exiting MalwareBytes, then re-enabling.